# How many outcomes are there for a race with $n$ horses?

Tags: combinatorics

In a race there are $n$ horses. In that race, more than one horse may get the same position. For example, a race with 2 horses can finish in 3 ways:

1. Both first
2. Horse 1 first and horse 2 second
3. Horse 2 first and horse 1 second

How can I find out the number of ways the race can finish for any $n$. Is there any recurrence relation to calculate the number of ways? I need help to understand the solving way with better explanation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact solution but by using this you can obtain the solution. I am giving a R code to obtain the solution. Suppose you have n=3 horces then

```
library(gtools)
n<-3
rank_horse <- permutations(n, n, v=1:n, set=TRUE, repeats.allowed=TRUE)
colnames(rank_horse) <- c('H1','H2','H3')
rank_horse

     H1 H2 H3
 [1,]  1  1  1
 [2,]  1  1  2
 [3,]  1  1  3
 [4,]  1  2  1
 [5,]  1  2  2
 [6,]  1  2  3
 [7,]  1  3  1
 [8,]  1  3  2
 [9,]  1  3  3
[10,]  2  1  1
[11,]  2  1  2
[12,]  2  1  3
[13,]  2  2  1
[14,]  2  2  2
[15,]  2  2  3
[16,]  2  3  1
[17,]  2  3  2
[18,]  2  3  3
[19,]  3  1  1
[20,]  3  1  2
[21,]  3  1  3
[22,]  3  2  1
[23,]  3  2  2
[24,]  3  2  3
[25,]  3  3  1
[26,]  3  3  2
[27,]  3  3  3
```

in this you can get all possible combinations now you need to treat 2,2,2 as 1,1,1 and 1,1,3 as 1,1,2 and so on.